# Emoticons in Flutter appearing as greyscale after update

Tags: flutter

after upgrading to flutter 3.7.5 all my colored emoticons started rendering as greyscale in Flutter web.

```dart
const Text(
               "Delivery: ",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: statusDeliveryColor),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: const Text(" "))
```

Renders as

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this? Similar behaviour with other emoticons such as the rocket, etc.